# Как удалить приложение находящееся на проверке Google Console?

Tags: java, android

Отправил приложение в Google Console. Оно находится на проверке. А сейчас нашёл в нём ошибку, которую не заметил раньше. Можно ли удалить приложение которое находится на проверке (и как) или придётся ждать пока придёт отказ?

Comment: Ждать не нужно, добавляйте новую версию

Answer (score 0):

Ничего сделать нельзя. Ждите отклонения приложения и заливайте новую версию.

Либо ждите бана приложения и/или аккаунта и подавайте аппеляцию.

Answer (score 0):

Приложение опубликуют, заливай новую версию, жди обновления

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/576955)

Comment: Является полным ответом на вопрос. Проходили это уже